# JsonResponse to array

Tags: django, jsonresponse

I use a django library function.

```
my_data = get_stats(request)
```

`get_stats` returns JsonResponse.

```
return JsonResponse({'data': response})
```

Every `response` object consists of 'id', 'name' and 'value'. I need to parse `my_data` to array - I need to get every item's `id, name and value`. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure `response` is object ? Try wrap with `json.loads(response)` and you have the object and make the for loop to get every id, name, value

Comment: @F'inAwesome  I can't change `get_stats` function - if you mean that.

Comment: No... I mean you said about id, name, value's in response so that's the way to parse the response...

Comment: @F'inAwesome I think it shall be `my_data['data']` or something like that - but all my efforts gives nothing.

Comment: Use `requests` library to get the `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsonResponse` body is in `my_data.content`
So rightful is

```
json.loads(my_data.content)
```